# iOS VoIP Notification Crashing Before Launch

Tags: ios, twilio, voip, callkit, pushkit

Our iOS app integrates with Twilio and is set up to receive PushKit VoIP notifications.

Occasionally and indeterminately, the app will crash before launching - preventing us from processing the push notification. This only occurs when the app has been fully force-quit.

```
Provision violated for watchdog process-launch: <FBSProcessResourceProvision: 0x281e68880; allowance: <; FBSProcessResourceAllowance; type: scheduledTime; timeValue: 5.0s>; violated: YES>
```

The codepath for processing the notification more or less passes it directly to Twilio, then takes the resulting CallKit structures and attempts to open CallKit. None of this codepath gets executed (or, at least logged) when this crash occurs.

Where can I start to understand why the Resource Allowance is being violated?

Comment: Hello @Patrick, Have you registered for PushKit notifications? Can you please give your AppDelegate code, so i can try the same. I have already implemented calling with Twilio, and everything is working 100% fine for me.

Comment: I think above log that you shared belongs to system, not to your app. Your app must be facing some other issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure with the abbreviation, but if it stand for FrontBoardServices, then your app seems taking to much time launching.

Examine your AppDelegte.
Whats is launched there that could be blocking and can it moved to a different thread?

Another Pitfall:
**PKRegistryDeleagte needs to be registered during the launch or quickly as possible, else you never get the Push.**

Comment: Specifically, the solution was to make the registry delegate association the first thing called in the `didFinishLaunching` method. If we attempted to do any view hierarchy instantiation beforehand, we'd run into the issue.